# no privilege in PhpMyAdmin from Wamp

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, privileges

I have been messing around trying to solve this problem for awhile now and I probably messed something up. I have been going around the forums and nothing has been working. First I forgot my password to root and used the command --skip-grant-tables to try to change it. I am able to login into root now on phpmyadmin with my password just being empty. On phpmyadmin it shows User: root@localhost. Then when I try to create a new database there is only a red x and is says No Privileges.

Also if I try to create a password to root I get an error that says - Can't find any matching row in the user table.

I saw on a forunm that said to run this code 
    select Host, User, Select_priv from mysql.user
but what I get it SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'user'

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command can be used to set the password for the root user and grant all privileges:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('NewPasswordHere') WHERE User='root';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Place this SQL code into a text file and save it some place convenient.  Then, kill the SQL server.  Open a command prompt and cd to the directory where the mysql-nt executable is stored.  Execute this command:

```
mysqld-nt --init-file=sql-file-saved-above.txt
```

Kill the SQL process you just started and restart the server normally and all should be good.  Depending on how you have phpMyAdmin configured, you might need to adjust its configuration if you have the root password saved there.

Comment: When i ran mysqld-nt I got an error that it is not reconized as a command. when I did the same code without the -nt    mysqld--init-file=sql.txt I got the error mysql: unknown variable "init-file=sql.txt"   the file i saved was called sql.txt

Comment: so the -nt part works, but I still get the same error of mysql: unknown variable "init-file=sql.txt"

Comment: are there any spaces between --init-file and between -file=sql.txt

Comment: @AustenNovis - Ah, I see.  Are you able to actually get to a MySQL console?  Can you run just the `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost'` and `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` lines from above?  What does it say in return?

Comment: @AustenNovis The command you should run is `mysqld --init-file=sql.txt`

Answer (score 0):

your best option is to set add a new user with a password and grant FULL privildeges, on you connection use the new user

Open PhpMyAdmin

select "Users"
underneath the know users is the option "add user"

add login information as required

tick the 2 boxes in the "database for users section"

now "Check All" in the Global privideges and click go, new user is then set up and you can use it as your new connection

Comment: I do not have any options that has Users

Answer (score 0):

go to Php My Admin home page of wamp

At the very top in grey you can see your connection is "localhost"
Underneath where you see your connection is local, are 10 tabs which are......

Databases |
SQL |
Status |
Users |
Export |
Import | 
Settings | 
Binary log |
Replication |
More

as you can see option 4 is "Users"

Comment: For some reason I do not have that it goes Databases,SQL,Status,Export,Import,Settings,Synchronize,Variables,Charsets,Engines